# Variable not defined in def ()

Tags: python, string, variables

It says `N` is not defined. But why? It is in `def szint()` Someone know what is the problem?

Sorry for not English. I could translate it if you want.

```
import random

def szint():
    N = int(input('Hanyadik emelet színezését kéred? (1.-50. szint) '))
    if N > 50 or N < 1:
        print('Ez nincs a megadott tartományban, válassz egy másik szintet!')
        szint()

def szinezes():
    I = int(input('Hanyadik fajtát? (1.-1 000 000 000 000 000. színezés) '))
    if I > 1000000000000000 or I < 1:
        print('Ez nincs a megadott tartományban, válassz egy másik szintet!')
        szinezes()

szint()
szinezes()

def variansok(length):  
    alap_szinezés = 'FPZ'
    varians = ''.join((random.choice(alap_szinezés)) for x in range(length))    
variansok(N)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. For debugging help in the future, please make a [mre] including the full error message and everything translated so that we can understand what's happening. For more tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 3):

`N` is *not* defined in your call to `variansok`. `N` is a local variable defined in `szint`. Once the call to `szint` returns, that variable is gone.

You could make `szint` define a global variable (and use a loop rather than recursion)

```
def szint():
    global N

    while True:
        N = int(input('Hanyadik emelet színezését kéred? (1.-50. szint) '))
        if 1 <= N <= 50:
            break
        print('Ez nincs a megadott tartományban, válassz egy másik szintet!')
```

but a better solution would be to *return* the value to define a variable that's in the same scope as the call to `variansok`.

```
def szint():    
    while True:
        N = int(input('Hanyadik emelet színezését kéred? (1.-50. szint) '))
        if 1 <= N <= 50:
            return N
        print('Ez nincs a megadott tartományban, válassz egy másik szintet!')

n = szint()

...

variansok(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

N is defined only inside szint() function.
You can either make the variable global or just return the value from the function like below

```
import random

def szint():
    N = int(input('Hanyadik emelet színezését kéred? (1.-50. szint) '))
    if N > 50 or N < 1:
        print('Ez nincs a megadott tartományban, válassz egy másik szintet!')
        szint()
    return N

def szinezes():
    I = int(input('Hanyadik fajtát? (1.-1 000 000 000 000 000. színezés) '))
    if I > 1000000000000000 or I < 1:
        print('Ez nincs a megadott tartományban, válassz egy másik szintet!')
        szinezes()

N = szint()
szinezes()

def variansok(length):  
    alap_szinezés = 'FPZ'
    varians = ''.join((random.choice(alap_szinezés)) for x in range(length))    
variansok(N)
```

Comment: It looks like you'd also need to capture the return value of the recursive call to `szint()`